# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'player' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, attributes, syntax-error

I am trying to create this object programatically:

```
var data = {
  "player0": {
    "name":     "kahn",
    "pos":      "gk",
    "ability":  "best",
    "unsure":   0,
    "waiting":  1
  },
  "player1": {
    "name" :    "recoba",
    "pos":      "cmf",
    "ability":  "inter",
    "unsure":   1,
    "waiting":  0
   }
};
```

This is my attempt, but I get the error displayed in the title:

```
var test;
test.player.name = "kahn";
test.player.pos = "gk"; // enough properties for testing
console.log(test);
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "programatically"? Do you want to clone an Object?

Comment: No @PHPglue, in my application I will have some data in real time, so in a loop, I must create an object like the one I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign object properties until you create object itself:

```
var test = {};
test.player = {};
test.player.name = "kahn";
...
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Or:

```
var test = {};

test.player = {name: "kahn", pos: "gk"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Or:

```
var test = [];

var player1 = {name: "kahn", pos: "gk"};
var player2 = {name: "recoba", pos: "cmf"};

test.push(player1);
test.push(player2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Or:

```
var test = {};

test.player0 = {name: "kahn", pos: "gk"};
test.player1 = {name: "recoba", pos: "cmf"};

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

*Note: the latter corresponds to yours object structure, given in question.*

Or:

```
var test = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test["player" + i] = {"name": "player " + i};
    ...
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: Side note: You don't have to `stringify` anything going into `console.log`.  Logging complex objects is its strength!

Comment: @ScottKaye, yes when you using latest firefox/chrome debug tools. I'm preferring old good Opera 11, and there console just prints `[object Object]` ='(

Comment: Thanks. However, I would like to ask another question please. In my real code I have a loop, where in the first loop I will fill `player0`, in the second loop `player1` and so on..How would you do it? First thing in mind is an if/else structure or a switch. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: you can assign properties in associated-array-like manner as well

Comment: Can you please update your answer for one last time with an example on that? :)

Comment: Holy crap, Opera *11*!?  The one from ~2010?

Comment: @ScottKaye, yeah =) I'm patiantly waiting for whole it's beauty implemented in new Opera... for around 5 years... %)